# Import Large SQL File

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a student conducting some research which involves a sort of data mining. I have several volunteer "node" servers which gather and produce SQL files for me to import on my server and analyze.

The problem is, these are very big files, and I need a way to import them quickly. The network recently expanded, and now there just isn't enough throughput on the hard drive for the MySQL console to import them as they come in. And time is important - there is a deadline for the research to be in, and I want to be actively gathering for as much time as possible beforehand and not have a queue waiting to be inserted.

I am wondering if there is a better way to import very large files - each one weighs in at about 100 MB. I've tried "\. myfile.sql"" but that is incredibly slow. PHPMyAdmin won't take files that big.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you use [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html)?

Comment: @PinnyM as i get **Connor Peet** deals with SQL-files, isn't? So  `mysqlimport` would be some extra here

Comment: Go for the CLI client option rather then PHPMyAdmin. But physical server limitations of course apply, tweaking MySQL config for optimal throughput might be more for serverfault.com

Comment: try to have a go at: http://daipratt.co.uk/importing-large-files-into-mysql-with-phpmyadmin/ if you have acesss to your config file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Large Table Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460943/mysql-large-table-import)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried `mysql -uYOU -p < myfile.sql` ?

UPD:

even `mysql -uYOU -p < myfile.sql &` if you have short-live remote console session

UPD2:

But most efficient way it's using `mysqlimport` as **PinnyM** advised.
Assuming `name_same_as_table.txt` is text file with DOS-style EOLs and tab-separated fields. Count and type of fields must be the same as in destination table.

```
mysqlimport -uYOU -p --lock-tables --lines-terminated-by="\r\n" --fields-terminated-by="\t" YOUR_DB name_same_as_table.txt
```

Comment: Ah, how would I execute that in Windows?

Answer (score -1):

XAMPP Windows Configuration

1. mysql.ini - 8m change to 200m(as we need)
2. navigate in cmd prompt to mysql/bin
3. place your sql file in mysql/bin folder

cmd: mysql -u username -p databasename < sqlFile.sql

4. it asks password : default empty pass in local host
5. wait several min(based up on sql file size)_ .. thats all :)

Comment: This is exactly what the previous answer proposed.