# How to import large .sql files

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have an issue. I am trying to create an installer for my content management system, that will make the process as simple and painless as possible. The upload size is around 8mb. I have a script that will process the sql file, but it does not allow ';' in strings, and this is no good for me. It also takes around an hour to process all queries.

Is there any way that I could import the sql file, in a short amount of time, and allow ';'s, within a varchar?

Comment: See my answer to [Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php/4028289#4028289) and also other answers I link to from that one. I'm not sure if it's exactly a duplicate, because you don't mention PHP. But the principle applies no matter what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify something like:

```
delimiter $$
```

At the beginning of your script and than restore:

```
delimiter ;
```

At the end of the script.
This will manage ; as a normal char during your import.

Comment: Thankyou for your fast reply! So, I would add this at the top of my sql file? Or within the PHP import?

Comment: At the beginning of the sql file and restore it at the end. This is normally used when you write a stored procedure in mysql to avoid partial execution of the script.

Comment: Sounds like the OP has some custom script that processes the .sql file, splits it on `;` and runs each statement. `DELIMITER` is a builtin command of the mysql client, and is not recognized by the MySQL server SQL parser. So I don't think this answer will help.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't know that DELIMITER was a mysql client command.

Answer (score 0):

mysql.ini - 8m change to 200m(as we need)

```
cmd: mysql -u username -p databasename < sqlFile.sql
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36737350/6223123